# Apache commons config: How to gat a particular value from config?

Tags: java, apache-commons

In my Spring web application I am using apache commons config to read an xml file, to load file paths. Have included the following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Used the following classes to read the xml file

```
ConfigurationPropertySource configurationPropertySource = new    ConfigurationPropertySource("xml configuration",
            new Configurations().xml("config.xml"));
```

My config.xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <configuration>
        <paths>
              <path name="Films" value="/files/films" />
              <path name="Music" value="/files/songs" />
              <path name="Docs" value="/files/docs" />
         </paths>
    </configuration>
```

By using code like  `String linkNormal = config.getString("paths.path[@name]");` I can get value "Films".

How can I use commons-config to read the `value` of a particular `path` like `Music`?

I need the value `/files/songs`

Comment: config.getString("paths.path[2][@name]"); ?? or something similar

Comment: can I give something like config.getString("paths.path[2][@name="Music"]");?